# "very well" in "I can't very well talk to you and concentrate on sanding this at the same time."

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning, idioms

What is the effect of "very well" in the phrase

> I can't **very well** talk to you and concentrate on sanding this at the same time.

Comment: Looks like *very well* is part of the larger expression: *can't/cannot/couldn't very well (do something)*. See https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/can-t-very-well-do-something and https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/cannot-very-well-do-something.

Answer (score 2):

The expression carries two or three effects:

1. Intensification: something like "absolutely can't".
2. Obviousness: bringing to the person's attention the fact that this is clearly not doable and they should have realized that.
3. Contradiction: highlighting the fact that what you can't do carries some inherent contradiction or impossibility.

> You can't very well go to Australia when you're still bedridden.

Note that this doesn't appear to be the same use as [the other one you identified](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/193859/he-might-very-well-say-that), which I would say is primarily concessive or dismissive depending on tone.

I would venture to say that "very well" only appears with modals, and that the senses above are triggered by negative modals (won't, can't, couldn't, etc.).

Comment: **very well** is not outdated where I come from.

Comment: @T I couldn't very well have known that! Just kidding. Where is that?

Comment: I'm in southeastern Pennsylvania (Central Atlantic AmE dialect). The phrase is used frequently in a wide variety of contemporary genres. "You can't very well send out questionnaires to every female in town, nor can you make a door-to-door survey."  *Married Men Make the Best Lovers* by Ruth Dickson. (2014) . "I can't afford to be off of work, and plus I can't very well tell them I need time off to kick my addiction." *What the Supplement Manufacturers Don't Want You to Know!* by Mark Wimberley (2002).

Comment: It's a synonym for "just" or "up and".

Comment: Meaning seems pretty in line then, but commonness not. Let me come back to this later...

Comment: The answer is extremely clear, regardless of any regionalism.