# "can (very) well do": is it the antonym of "can't (very) well do"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, word-meaning, idioms, modal-verbs

There is already discussion on *cannot very well do* in the forum: ["very well" in "I can't very well talk to you and concentrate on sanding this at the same time."](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/194091/very-well-in-i-cant-very-well-talk-to-you-and-concentrate-on-sanding-this-at)

And I'd like to raise two new questions based on instances I've seen variations of this expression used. (*btw I feel unsure whether this sentence I just wrote is gramatically correct*)

1. Can I omit the *very*?

Because it seems Chomsky has done this in *Language and Thought*.

> Frege's basic assumption is that "mankind possesses a common treasure of thoughts which is transmitted from generation to generation," something that "**cannot well be denied**."

2. The rarely seen *can (very) well do* meaning obviousness or appropriateness: can it be safely used as the antonym of *can't (very) well do*?

I reckon it can well be confused with *can well do* meaning ability or ... ableness? But there is this example from WSJ:

> It’s at least conceivable, then, that Xi **could very well begin** to privately pressure Putin to find a way out of the war and back to some semblance of global stability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To question one:

It's perfectly correct, 'very' is merely an intensifier. It is not a very common form, though.

To question two:

It's hard to imagine every context, but yes. To give a straightforward example:

He can't very well raise taxes
He can very well raise taxes

Mean the opposite to each other.